# syntax to get min from two tables

Tags: min

i have two different tables

```
table1 - property
=================

id,name, address, city state, zip
```

---

```
table2 - floorvalue
===================

id, rentmin, rentmax, bedrooms, bathrooms
```

i need a query to fetch min rent values from the two tables, the current below query getting for eg two records with all the values like property id, name, city, state and then floor id, rmin, rmax etc. but i need the first minimum rent if i get two or more records of the same id.

query i have :

```
select
  p.id,
  p.name,
  p.address,
  p.city,
  p.state,
  p.zip,
  f.id,
  f.rmin,
  f.rmax,
  f.bedrooms,
  f.bathrooms 
from property as p, floorvalue as f 
where p.city = 'losangeles' and p.state = 'ca' and p.id = f.id
```

Comment: Looks like your query will return all of the data in both tables, including the `rmin` field. Are you looking for something more specific?

Comment: yes along with returning all of the data i need only to get the first minimum rent value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM property AS p, floorvalue AS f
WHERE p.id = f.id
ORDER BY f.rentmin
LIMIT 1
```

this will show the values related to the apartment whose minimum rent is minimal among tables. i hope this is what you need.

Comment: actually i need all the datas but with a sort of minimum rent

Comment: but this will give all the values, for eg if i have two records with the same values but only the minimum rent will vary then how i can only the first minimum value (ie only one record)

Comment: ok, you really need to be more precise with your questions. you wrote that you need minimum rent valueS from two tables. not only that you have a bit of ambiguity since one of your fields is called rentmin, but you also use plural form. another edit comming up.

Answer (score 0):

... AND f.rentmin = (select min(rentmin) from floorvalue f2, property p2 where ... your condition)

it could be written in a single select thouhg.